# Question about the chromatic polynomials of a graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

Let $G$ be a simple graph. Then the chromatic polynomial $X_G(q)$ has the following well-known expressions:

$$X_G(q) = \sum\limits_{\pi \in L_G}\mu(\hat 0,\pi)q^{|\pi|}$$ where $L_G$ is the set of all partitions of the vertex set in which each part induces a connected subgraph.

$$X_G(q) = \sum\limits_{S \subseteq E(G)}(-1)^{|S|} q^{c(S)}$$
where $c(S)$ is the number of connected components in the spanning subgraph $G_S$ of $G$ with edge set $S$.

Given a set $S \subset E$, the vertex set of the connected componenets of $G_S$ leads to an element of $L_G$. Call this map $\Phi$. Conversely, given $\pi \in L_G$, the union of edge set of its parts leads to a subset of $E(G)$.

Fix $\pi \in L_G$. By comparing the coefficients in the above two equations we have $$\sum\limits_{\substack{S \subseteq E(G) \\ \Phi(S) = \pi}}(-1)^{|S|} = \mu(\hat 0,\pi).$$

My questions are

1. how to describe $\Phi^{-1}(\pi)$?
2. Does the map $\Phi$ is injective for Trees?

Thank you.

Comment: 1. Choose a spanning subset of edges for each component in pi. 2. Yes, since clearly each component of a tree has at most one spanning subset.

Comment: @Sam Hopkins Each component $p_i$ of $\pi = (p_1,\dots,p_m)$ can have many spanning subsets of edges, say $E^i_1,\dots,E^i_{k_i}$. Let $S = \cup_{i=1}^mE_{j_i}^i$  for some $1 \le j_i \le k_i$  is one inverse image and all the inverse images are obtained in this way? Thank you.

Comment: Also, how many spanning subsets of edges a connected graph $G$ has? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you should get all inverse images that way. The number of spanning subsets is a Tutte polynomial evaluation (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_polynomial#(1,2)) but I don't think there's a simple formula for it.

Comment: Thank you. It was a helpful discussion.